# Rearrange text on SAS

Tags: sas

I can not find the way to reverse text strings.

For example I want to reverse these:

- `MMMM121231M34` to become `43M132121MMMM`
- `MM1M11M1` to become `1M11M1MM`
- `1111213111` to become `1113121111`

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Do you want to reverse whatever you have in the input?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your examples, what you mean by 'rearrange' is actually 'reverse'.
In that case, you've got the very handy `reverse()` function in SAS.

Used in context:

```
data test;
  length text $32;
  infile datalines;
  input text $;
  result=reverse(strip(text));
datalines;
MMMM121231M34
MM1M11M1
1111213111
;
run;
```

EDIT on @Joe's request: in the particular example above, I create the `test` dataset by setting a length of 32 characters for the `text` variable. Therefore, when reading the values from `datalines`, these are padded with blanks up to that total of 32 characters. Hence, when reversing that value, the result has that many blanks at the start, followed by the actual value you are looking for. By adding the `strip` function, you remove the excess blanks from the value of `text` before reversing, keeping only the "real" value in the result.

Comment: You might want to explain why you added `strip`, as I think the spaces-at-the-end is tricky for a lot of people.